# How to exclude iPad Mini support?

Tags: ipad, ipad-mini

My app only has retina images, so I am including front-facing-camera as a device capability to exclude non-retina iPhone devices; however, this does not account for iPad devices. How can i exclude non-retina iPad devices, such as the iPad mini, from my app? If not possible, then is there a way to exclude all iPad devices from my app?

Comment: That's a crappy reason to not support devices IMHO.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I could duplicate my files quite easily and just rename them. That shouldn't take more than a couple hours. Thanks for the inspiration haha.

Comment: Don't just rename them. The non-retina images need to have half the width and height.

Comment: That's what I meant. It's relatively easy to resize the images (takes about 15 seconds each), and after that I just have to rename it. I think that trying to avoid adding non-retina support added more work than just doing that.

Comment: Some images may not look very good after scaling. It's fine for photos but toolbar icons and other icons typically don't scale very well. After creating all of the non-retina images, you should see how each looks in the app.

Comment: Will do! I have an illustrator file with all of the images, but there are some 200-300 of them, so it would take a while to port all of them individually. Thanks for the help!